# Altered Django model. I provided a one-off default = datetime.date for DateField. Found that it's invalid. Removed the field and still can't migrate

Tags: python, linux, django, datetime, models

Hi here's the specific line that I added in models.py

`billingMonth2 = models.DateTimeField()`

This is what happened in makemigrations, I figured I added a non nullable field so I tried to define a default value:

```
    You are trying to add a non-nullable field 'billingMonth' to bills 
    without a default; we can't do that (the database needs something to populate
    existing rows).
    Please select a fix:
    1) Provide a one-off default now (will be set on all existing rows)
    2) Quit, and let me add a default in models.py
    Select an option: 1
    Please enter the default value now, as valid Python
    The datetime and django.utils.timezone modules are available, so you can do 
    e.g. timezone.now()
    >>> datetime.date
    Migrations for 'bills':
    0007_auto_20160609_1400.py:
    - Change Meta options on bills
    - Add field billingMonth to bills
```

I found out that datetime.date was invalid and came out with an error

```
    ....File "/home/jrbenriquez/Envs/env1/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/backends/base/schema.py", line 197, in effective_default
default = field.get_default()
    File "/home/jrbenriquez/Envs/env1/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/fields/__init__.py", line 797, in get_default
return self.default()
    TypeError: Required argument 'year' (pos 1) not found
```

So I just removed the billingMonth2 field hoping it would go back to normal and also setting a default value  as

```
    `billingMonth2 = models.DateTimeField(default='Test',null=True,blank=True)`
```

Both still gives the same error. 
It seems to me I have changed something within the meta of the model in some other file or in the database and that I have to delete the default value "datetime.date" somewhere

I hope someone could help me here. Thanks!

UPDATE:
Here's 0007_auto20160609_1400.py

```
    # -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
    # Generated by Django 1.9.6 on 2016-06-09 14:00
    from __future__ import unicode_literals

    from django.db import migrations, models
    import django.utils.datetime_safe


    class Migration(migrations.Migration): 

        dependencies = [
            ('bills', '0006_bills_duedate'),
        ]

        operations = [
            migrations.AlterModelOptions(
                name='bills',
                options={'ordering': ('-id', '-status'),     'verbose_name_plural': 'Bills'},
             ),
            migrations.AddField(
                model_name='bills',
                name='billingMonth',
                field=models.DateField(default=django.utils.datetime_safe.date),
                preserve_default=False,
             ),
]
```

Comment: Can you post the content of `0007_auto_20160609_1400.py` in your migrations folder?

Comment: Hi, I have updated the question

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
Please enter the default value now, as valid Python
The datetime and django.utils.timezone modules are available, so you can do e.g. timezone.now()
>>> datetime.date
```

I guess it is asking for the return value of the method, not the method itself. So its `datetime.date()` with the `()` at the end.

Also, in your model's field declaration, you can set the current date as a default, if that's what you tried to do

```
billingMonth2 = models.DateTimeField(default=datetime.date, null=True, blank=True)
```

There you give it the method itself, without the `()`, so that the time is taken when a new row is created, not only when the model is first defined.

Comment: Thanks for that! But all I need now is to get rid of the error. Even though I have deleted the field it still pops up.

Comment: No, in the model its *without* `()`, only `datetime.date`. Try the Python console to see the difference between `datetime.date` and `datetime.date()`.

Comment: Tried: billingMonth2 = models.DateTimeField(default=datetime.date, null=True, blank=True)            

Still I get the same error, when I migrate.

Comment: Is `0007` the latest migration file? Updating the line `field=models.DateField(default=django.utils.datetime_safe.date)` and adding a `()` behind `date` should (probably) fix it. So the line should be `field=models.DateField(default=django.utils.datetime_safe.date())`. That should (possibly) add an actual `date` type as the default during migration.

Comment: I tried removing the field then adding the addfield from 0007 to the latest migration file and still it still comes up with the error. And also even though I delete the field billingMonth2 it still wont migrate.

Comment: Hi, I found that I had too many unapplied migrations upto 0018 from 0007 and they contained the same faulty datetime.date. Although I had to insert a sample date such as datetime.date(2016,06,06) to make all the migrations happen. After this problem is solved! Thanks

Comment: I had to use `datetime.date.today` which worked on my version 1.9

Answer (score 3):

During Makemigrations use: datetime.date.today() for fill DB or you'll get "TypeError: function missing required argument 'year' (pos 1)".

Answer (score 2):

Checkout this image:

[image: Checkout this image]

Try the following. Note: **You will lose all the data in your DB!**

1. Delete all the migrations in your app (say: 001_initial.py)
2. Delete the database (for me db.sqlite3,it's django provided one)
   (If have external one, drop the db and create new one)
3. Atlast run : python manage.py makemigrations
4. Python manage.py migrate

After that you can run normally.

Hope it will be helpful.

Answer (score 1):

Please enter the default value now, as valid Python
The datetime and django.utils.timezone modules are available, so you can do e.g. timezone.now()

> > > datetime.date
> > > or
> > > timezone.now()

or
timezone.now